# Java Program Flow and OOP

Tags: java, oop

I'm a Java newbie, and also new to OOP.  I have been a procedural programmer for years, but now trying to learn OOP.  I am trying to write a basic program for practice as I go through an online Java course.  It's a program to track people's score for games.  Here's what I'd like to happen:
1. Ask user for the number of players.
2. Ask for the names of the players.
3. Display the main program window for tracking score.

I am using Swing.  My code currently displays a JTextField for #1 above.  My thoughts were that I'd put an ActionListenter on the JTextField which would get/store the number of players when the user hits enter.  This works.  But the next steps are where I'm having problems with the OOP.  Here is the code for my ActionListener:

```
private class InputHandler implements ActionListener
{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        String enteredText = e.getActionCommand();
        numPlayers = Integer.parseInt(enteredText.trim());
    }
}
```

Since I need the program to wait until I have numPlayers, I decided to instantiate the class to get the player names inside of that ActionListener.  However, since this class is an ActionListener, there are restrictions on what I can/can't do in there.  The class I want to instantiate is called GetPlayerNames, and it's just a public class that extends JFrame.  I have tried putting this into actionPerformed (within InputHandler):

```
GetPlayerNames temp = new GetPlayerNames(numPlayers);
```

(I used "temp" here because I don't need to do anything with this variable...it's just the only way I could get it to work), but of course this gives a compiler warning because "temp" is never used.  And of course, it's messy and bad form.  Help?

Comment: Just a quick tip (more of an opinion): I wouldn't start off learning Java/OOP with Swing. I'd start with a program than can be executed from the command line. That way you don't have to deal with the intricacies of Swing *and* OOP at the same time.

Comment: Yep GUI programming is really a different beast (and honestly an extremely annoying one at that :p - your mileage may vary). Though from a OOP perspective extending JFrame is in most cases the wrong approach and a decorator is the better way

Comment: I agree with user18... absolutely. Java is a verbose language as-is; the need for private classes to handle UI action-events is a relic of a language that has no lambdas yet.

Comment: Not really an answer to your issue, but it seems you are still thinking procedurally. `1. Ask user for the number of players.
2. Ask for the names of the players.
3. Display the main program window for tracking score.` Would become: `Main program prompts for number of players and creates this many player objects. These Player objects when created prompt for name.` The main program displays the objects it has. I'm sure this is what you'll do, but I find the way I phrase a solution has an impact on how I implement it.

Comment: @user183037 I actually did start with command line stuff and worked with that for a couple of weeks.  Now I'm moving to Swing.  Incidentally, I did notice that in the javadocs they recommend that you don't write your own layouts but use a layout manager.  I'll go down that route now.  But I think my OOP/flow issue would be the same regardless...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Also, because your ActionListener is a nested class, it can call methods in its parent class:

```
public class Game {

    private void initUI() {
        // ...
        textField.addActionListener(new InputHandler());
        // ...
    }

    // ...

    private void showPlayerNameFrame(int numPlayers) {
        GetPlayerNames playerNameFrame = new GetPlayerNames(numPlayers);
        playerNameFrame.setVisible(true);
    }

    // ...

    private class InputHandler implements ActionListener {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            String enteredText = e.getActionCommand();
            int numPlayers = Integer.parseInt(enteredText.trim());
            showPlayerNameFrame(numPlayers);
        }
    }
}
```

This can make your code clearer because the objects which 'own' the logic (in this case the Game class) are the ones performing the actual actions.

Usually it makes sense for the action listeners to only parse the action and pass off the handling to the class. This is because often many types of listeners may trigger the same event (e.g value change listeners, action listeners, mouse listeners)

Instead of an *inner class*, one can also use an *anonymous class*:

```
public class Game {

    private void initUI() {
        // ...
        textField.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                String enteredText = e.getActionCommand();
                int numPlayers = Integer.parseInt(enteredText.trim());
                showPlayerNameFrame(numPlayers);
            }
        });
        // ...
    }

    // ...

    private void showPlayerNameFrame(int numPlayers) {
        GetPlayerNames playerNameFrame = new GetPlayerNames(numPlayers);
        playerNameFrame.setVisible(true);
    }

    // ...
}
```

With Java 8, you can also use a *Lambda* or a *Method Reference* instead of an anonymous class to achieve the same.

Lambda:

```
public class Game {

    private void initUI() {
        // ...
        textField.addActionListener(e -> {
            String enteredText = e.getActionCommand();
            int numPlayers = Integer.parseInt(enteredText.trim());
            showPlayerNameFrame(numPlayers);
        });
        // ...
    }

    // ...

    private void showPlayerNameFrame(int numPlayers) {
        GetPlayerNames playerNameFrame = new GetPlayerNames(numPlayers);
        playerNameFrame.setVisible(true);
    }

    // ...
}
```

Method Reference:

```
public class Game {

    private void initUI() {
        // ...
        textField.addActionListener(this::showPlayerNameFrame);
        // ...
    }

    // ...

    private void showPlayerNameFrame(ActionEvent e) {
        String enteredText = e.getActionCommand();
        int numPlayers = Integer.parseInt(enteredText.trim());
        showPlayerNameFrame(numPlayers);
    }

    private void showPlayerNameFrame(int numPlayers) {
        GetPlayerNames playerNameFrame = new GetPlayerNames(numPlayers);
        playerNameFrame.setVisible(true);
    }

    // ...
}
```

In most cases, Method References are probably the best way to implement ActionListeners in terms of maintainability and readability of source code.

Comment: I had tried something similar to this (but not the same) but I got compiler errors.  Your suggestion works!  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like your GetPlayerNames class' constructor sets the frame to visible. That's probably not a good idea. What if, for example, you wanted to create the frame and pre-load some large images without showing the frame, so that it shows up quickly when you do want it?

Something like this would make more sense and be "more OO" in my opinion:

```
GetPlayerNames playerNameFrame = new GetPlayerNames(numPlayers);
playerNameFrame.setVisible(true);
```

(I'm writing this from memory. It might be show() instead of setVisible(), but you get the idea)

**Update:**

I would also suggest looking at the [Model-View-Presenter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model-view-presenter) design pattern for user interfaces.

Comment: Ok, this is where I think I'm going off track.  Reading your answer, it sounds like you would only have one frame?  The way I was going I start with a frame just to get the number of players, and then once I have the number of players I hide that frame and then create a new frame for the next step.  Kind of like a wizard.  Would it be better to handle it all with one frame?

Comment: I wasn't really advocating any particular UI approach. My suggestion was more about avoiding side effects in constructors. I'm going to see if I can find a good MVP link and add that to my answer, too. That should give you some good perspective on OO GUI development.

Comment: Further, for event driven OO programming, I wouldn't even ask for the number of players. I'd have a "lobby" pre-game stage that can show the players, has an "Add Player" button, a "Remove" button for each listed player, and a "Play Game" button to leave pre-game setup and start the game with the players that have been added. Asking for the count before asking for the items is very procedural & command-line oriented.